# Separate a column into 2 columns at the last underscore in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe like this

```
id <-c("1","2","3")
col <- c("CHB_len_SCM_max","CHB_brf_SCM_min","CHB_PROC_S_SV_mean")

df <- data.frame(id,col)
```

I want to create 2 columns by separating the "col" into the measurement and stat. stat is basically the text after the last underscore (max,min,mean, etc)

My **desired output** is

```
  id   Measurement stat
   1   CHB_len_SCM  max  
   2   CHB_brf_SCM  min   
   3 CHB_PROC_S_SV mean
```

I tried it this way but the stat column in empty. I am not sure if I am pointing to the last underscore.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
  # Separate the sensors and the summary statistic
  separate(col, into = c("Measurement", "stat"),sep = '\\_[^\\_]*$')
```

What am I missing here? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We could use `extract` by capturing as two groups by making sure that the second group have one or more characters that are not a `_` until the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   extract(col, into = c("Measurement", "stat"), "(.*)_([^_]+)$")
#   id   Measurement stat
#1  1   CHB_len_SCM  max
#2  2   CHB_brf_SCM  min
#3  3 CHB_PROC_S_SV mean
```

---

Or using `separate` with a regex lookaround

```
df %>% 
   separate(col, into = c("Measurement", "stat"), sep="_(?=[^_]+$)")
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks akrun for showing both 'extract' and 'separate'.