# split column having uneven character length values into two columns - one for characters & another for numerics

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in long table format like this one below:

```rb
mydf <- data.frame(id = c(123, 123, 123),
                   name =c("test_2001", "test_area_2002", "test_area_sqkm_2003"),
                   value = c(15, 20, 25))
mydf

#>     id                 name  value
#> 1  123            test_2001     15
#> 2  123       test_area_2002     20
#> 3  123  test_area_sqkm_2003     25
```

After taking reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293534/split-values-of-a-column-and-store-only-numeric-values-in-a-different-column) here, I applied function `separate` from package `tidyr`:

```rb
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>% 
  separate(name, c("name","year"), extra="merge", fill = "left")

#>     id  name            year  value
#> 1  123  test            2001     15
#> 2  123  test       area_2002     20
#> 3  123  test  area_sqkm_2003     25
```

But I couldn't figure out how to split characters and numbers into two different columns like this:

```rb
desired.df

#>      id           name  year value
#> 1   123           test  2001    15
#> 2   123      test_area  2002    20
#> 3   123 test_area_sqkm  2003    25
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Just set `sep="_(?=[^_]+$)"`, as answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518137/separate-a-column-into-2-columns-at-the-last-underscore-in-r) because you essentially want to split on last `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bit of an explanation `(?<=[a-z])_(?=[1-9])` matches an `_`, then looks forward for a digit, `(?=[1-9])` and looks back for a letter, `(?<=[a-z])`, since that's what we want to split the string on.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
    separate(name, sep="(?<=[a-z])_(?=[1-9])", into=c("name", "year"))
```

```
   id           name year value
1 123           test 2001    15
2 123      test_area 2002    20
3 123 test_area_sqkm 2003    25
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like the following you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(id = c(123, 123, 123),
                   name =c("test_2001", "test_area_2002", "test_area_sqkm_2003"),
                   value = c(15, 20, 25))

mydf %>% 
  separate(name, sep="_(?=\\d+$)", into = c("name", "year"))

#>    id           name year value
#> 1 123           test 2001    15
#> 2 123      test_area 2002    20
#> 3 123 test_area_sqkm 2003    25
```